# How do I reattach the coupling nut to the strainer tailpiece?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, sink, leaking

[image]Kitchen Sink: Gap between Coupling Nut & Strainer Tailpiece ([image]what happened? lasted 12 years then doesn't fit)

Photo 1 (the tailpiece and coupling nut)
Video (under the kitchen sink - water dripping out of indicated gap)

I want to know if its an easy fix, or is this a replace all of the parts...not even sure where to order the parts.

Photo attached:
Video link of leak: https://photos.app.goo.gl/CepX3CvxD1tnE6NWA

Update:
I've added the missing gasket. It leaks a lot less (its down to a slight drip) Is the next missing part to replace: https://www.rona.ca/en/product/slip-joint-nut-abs-1-1-2-black-1236403

Comment: That bit never needed to fit. It's a compression joint, the metal flange should marry tightly to make the seal. The screw is just to maintain that tightness, not to provide the seal itself . The video looks like someone gunked it up with something previously. Whether that's to compensate for a poor fit is hard to tell. A closeup of the other side of the joint might help.

Comment: Appears to be missing a gasket (now) - perhaps the person with the blue gunk threw it away? Or it's still stuck to the sink? Anyway, the seal is not between the pipe and the nut, it's between the pipe and the sink, and the nut just holds it in place (as @Tetsujin said.) You need to clean off that glop and get a new gasket.

Comment: Also… the change in colouration across the flange would suggest the two never did marry quite square, but always at an angle.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like everything is metal compression. If you go to your local hardware store, you should be able to buy a rubber washer for the inside of that ring (common for chrome pipe fittings). [Here's an example from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-1-2-in-Sink-Drain-Pipe-Flanged-Rubber-Washer-2-Pack-C7195C/205153791)

[image: Rubber washer]

Comment: Note that the rubber washer is not flat - it's got an inner flange that fits inside the pipe opening on the bottom (the tailpiece).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the gap in the second picture, it appears to me to be one of two possibilities:

1. The nut you've got is somehow misshapen creating that gap in the picture.

   - Simply replace the nut and you should be fine.
2. You've got a 1-1/2" nut and strainer outlet, but a 1-1/4" drain pipe, leaving that gap visible.

   - Replace the drain pipe with a 1-1/2" piece to seal properly.
   - Replace the nut, just to be on the safe side.

In either case, you're going to want to clean off as much of the blue goop from the strainer tail piece as you can. You don't want it to be in the way of the threads of the new nut making a good seal. If the threads do seal properly, you won't need it anyway.

Comment: The threads don't seal on this type of joint - the threads are NOT the seal. They just hold parts together, and one of those parts is the gasket that does the sealing.

Comment: Thanks FreeMan - Update:
I've added the missing  (tailpiece washer) gasket. It leaks a lot less (its down to a slight drip) Is the next missing part to replace: https://www.rona.ca/en/product/slip-joint-nut-abs-1-1-2-black-1236403